Split large text file into smaller chunks by byte size and to retain end of line
I have python code which splits a file into smaller chunks with byte size, for example filename.txt being 1GB split into 10 smaller files of 100MB - filename_001.txt, filename_002.txt etc.
However although I'm happy with the file size splitting I noticed within these smaller split files the file contents can be cut anywhere on the line, but I would like to retain the line and split at the end of the line with the byte size.
See the following code I have:
import os
import sys

def getfilesize(sfilename):
    with open(sfilename,"rb") as fr:
        fr.seek(0,2) # move to end of the file
        size=fr.tell()
        print("getfilesize: size: %s" % size)
        return fr.tell()

def splitfile(spath, sfilename, splitsize, dpath):
    # Open original file in read only mode
    if not os.path.isfile(spath + sfilename):
        print("No such file as: \"%s\"" % spath + sfilename)
        return

    filesize=getfilesize(spath + sfilename)

    fullsfilepath = spath + sfilename
    fulldfilepath = dpath + sfilename

    with open(spath + sfilename,"rb") as fr:
        counter=1
        orginalfilename = fullsfilepath.split(".")
        newfilename = fulldfilepath.split(".")
        print(orginalfilename)
        readlimit = 5000 #read 5kb at a time
        n_splits = filesize//splitsize
        print("splitfile: No of splits required: %s" % str(n_splits))
        for i in range(n_splits+1):
            chunks_count = int(splitsize)//int(readlimit)
            data_5kb = fr.read(readlimit) # read
            # Create split files
            print("chunks_count: %d" % chunks_count)

            with open(newfilename[0]+"_{id}.".format(id=str(counter))+newfilename[1],"ab") as fw:
                fw.seek(0)
                fw.truncate()# truncate original if present
                while data_5kb:
                    fw.write(data_5kb)
                    if chunks_count:
                        chunks_count-=1
                        data_5kb = fr.read(readlimit)
                    else: break
            counter+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 4: print("Missing argument: Usage: filesplit.py sfilename splitsizeinkb dfilename")
    else:
        filesize = int(sys.argv[3]) * 1000 #make into kb
        spath = sys.argv[1]
        sfilename = sys.argv[2]
        dpath = sys.argv[4]
        splitfile(spath, sfilename, filesize, dpath)

Is it possible to achieve this? If so how can this be done?

How about splitting on number of lines having the overall count. Also, readlimit could be a multiple of 4096 and big enough to reduce the number of reads 1024*1024*1024*1024/4096 = 268435456. ~260M reads with readlimi 4096

Please use the internationally agreed SI units. For gigabytes, use GB because gb is not defined and Gb is gigabits. Likewise please use MB for megabytes, since your mb would read as millibits.

What do you expect to happen when you retain a line at the end of a chunk? Do you leave out the incomplete line so that the size of the chunk does not exceed the maximum chunk size? Or do you want the rest of the line to be included even though it would make the chunk size larger than the maximum chunk size?

GNU Parallel will do that for you without writing any Python, e.g. parallel --pipe --block 100m wc :::: YOURFILE

@blhsing either way is fine - I understand that the split files would not all be exact same size but close to the specified chunk size

Maybe you should get max lines size first,then you would know how may you should set the size of chunk.Here are the codes that may help:
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def lines_max_size(filepath: str):
    """
    iter file content by size and return max fize of them

    Args:
        filepath (str): path of file to iter
    """
    ans = 0
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            size = sys.getsizeof(line)
            if size > ans:
                ans = size
    return ans


def split_file(filepath: str, chunk_size: int, outfile_prefix):
    """
    split large file to smaller files by lines, whiches size will lower than chunk_size

    Args:
         filepath (str): path of file to split
         chunk_size (str): size the files after spliting should be lower than, unit - bytes
         outfile_prefix (str): name of output files should be in the format - outfile_prefix+count_number
    """
    content = ""
    count = 1
    save_path = Path(filepath).parent
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line_size = sys.getsizeof(line)
            if line_size > chunk_size:
                raise Exception("current line size is %s, chunk_size - %s too small to splite file by lines" % (
                    line_size,
                    chunk_size
                ))

            if sys.getsizeof(content+line) <= chunk_size:
                content += line
            else:
                fn = outfile_prefix + str(count) + filepath.split(".")[-1]
                fp = save_path.joinpath(fn)
                with open(fp, "w") as fw:
                    fw.write(content)
                content = line
                count += 1
    if content:
        fn = outfile_prefix + str(count) + filepath.split(".")[-1]
        fp = save_path.joinpath(fn)
        with open(fp, "w") as fw:
            fw.write(content)


def list_files_content_size(path: Path, file_prefix: str):
    """
    under path, list size of file's content, those files' name starts with file_prefix

    Args:
        path (Path): files under this path to list
        file_prefix (str): files name should start with 
"""
    for fn in os.listdir(path):
        if not fn.startswith(file_prefix):
            continue
        fp = path.joinpath(fn)
        with open(fp, "r") as f:
            size = sys.getsizeof(f.read())
            print(fn, str(size) + "bytes")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = "a.txt"
    #Firstly,get max fize of lines 
    print("max size of lines is: ", lines_max_size(filepath))

    # Then, split large file
    split_file(filepath="a.txt", chunk_size=240, outfile_prefix="output")

    # list out files's size
    current_path = Path(__file__).parent
    list_files_content_size(current_path, "output")


Thanks for sharing this code, I have tried it out with my large txt file but it takes quite a long time to run unfortunately
